# Broadcasting a numpy array into an array of larger size using an index array

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a very large 2D numpy array (A) and a smaller 2D array (B) that is smaller in both dimensions. B is square. I have an index array that is the same length as B. Like this:

```
A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
B = np.array([[2, 4, 5, 7],
              [2, 7, 1, 3],
              [6, 1, 3, 5],
              [1, 6, 3, 2]])
Index = np.array([0, 1, 5, 6])
```

I want to add the contents of B to A in the rows and columns defined by Index. A is not necessarily full of 0's so it needs to be addition. The result would look like this:

```
R = np.array([2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0],
             [2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0],
             [1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I've tried doing it with this:

```
A[Index, Index] += B
```

Which gives me the following error `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,4) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,)`

I don't understand why this doesn't work, because I can do this:

```
A[Index, Index[0]:Index[0]+4] = B
```

And then values will all appear in the correct rows but not the correct columns. Which makes sense, because I'm just giving it a block of 4 columns for it to appear in, but I would like it to appear in the columns defined by Index.

I also tried np.add.at(A[Index], Index, B) which gives me `IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4.` I don't think I understand why it's trying access index 6 in B, which has size 4.

Comment: Read more about numpy indexing.  `x[i,i]` gives a 'diagonal', not a block.  `x[np.ix_(i,i]]` does the block.  Read the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing with arrays uses `broadcasting`.  Using 2 (4,) arrays as indices, produces s (4,) shape result:

```
In [205]: A[Index,Index].shape
Out[205]: (4,)

In [206]: np.ix_(Index,Index)
Out[206]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [5],
        [6]]),
 array([[0, 1, 5, 6]]))
```

`ix_` makes a (4,1) and (1,4) array.  Those broadcast together to index a (4,4) shape:

```
In [207]: A[np.ix_(Index,Index)].shape
Out[207]: (4, 4)
```

which matches your `B`:

```
In [208]: A[np.ix_(Index,Index)] = B
```

There's a major numpy indexing page, and these kinds of details are handled in the `advanced indexing` section.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `np.repeat()` for repeating the index on the row axis, and `np.tile()` for repeating the index on the column axis.

That gives you an index that has the following pattern:

```
>>> np.repeat(Index, index_len), np.tile(Index, index_len)
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 5, 6, 0, 1, 5, 6, 0, 1, 5, 6, 0, 1, 5, 6]))
```

Then, you can index into A with this.

```
index_len = len(Index)
A[np.repeat(Index, index_len), np.tile(Index, index_len)] = B.flatten()
```

(`B.flatten()` is required because the shape on the left hand side is also flattened.)

Result:

```
array([[2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0, 0],
       [2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0],
       [1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I would have recommended `np.ix_` instead of tile and repeat.